# Corrupt quicktime movie repair or recovery of some content

Tags: python, quicktime

I would like to try to repair (or at least recover) content from some corrupt movie files I have.  I was wondering if anyone could give me a good starting point in terms of what python  modules to look at. I was also looking to this as a project to keep my coding skills sharp while I am job hunting.

I have seem some applications in the mac app store which seem to be written for the casual user needing to do some really basic fixes. I would like to understand better what is going on under the hood and have some control over the recovery process. It is very frustrating to spend the time running a recovery; only to get a very obtuse answer as a result.  If there is a better place to ask this quick; please point me to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what do you call 'corrupted video'. If there's no indexing, because of which usually most video players refuses to play the video, this can be done with `mencoder` or `ffmpeg`.

For example this command fixed video indexing issue:

```
mencoder -idx input.avi -ovc copy -oac copy -o output.avi
```

There are plenty of video issues out there and you need to know how to handle each of them. I'm sure you'll find plenty of topic on web for recovering videos with these tools. So all you need is [ffmpeg](https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) or [mencoder](https://code.google.com/p/pymencoder/) wrappers if you want to write tools with python

Comment: You kind of hit the nail on the head; I would like to be able to tell exactly what is wrong. Most of these movies came off a smart card that  started to die.

Comment: well usually the software which fixing problems, just "an attend" to fix those movies. and there are common issues that software tries to solve. it's not always successes :) I just showed you how to use most powerful tool in unix with python. Even osx apps has adopted them for converting stuff (usually they do).